# Error Register Assembly visual web part

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, telerik

I'm developing a web part in SharePoint 2013 using VS2012. 
In this web part I'm trying to use third party dll controls like telerik but i face a problem :

```
Could not load file or assembly......
```

and the file .ascx.g.cs will be empty when add register line as bellow :

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
```

I try to add dlls to gac and also try to add dlls to package but didn't fix my problem 
any suggestions??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need the full four part assembly name, with the Assembly, Version, Culture and PublicKey, to reference an assembly in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

yes its work with James Answer and to be more clear I wrote it as :

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2011.3.1115.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" %>
```

For my case thanks